# Issue getting basic slider to display using jQuery Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm attempting to use the jQuery version of Revolution Slider following this tutorial without the visual interface: https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/anatomy-basic-slider/. I'm not getting any errors in the Developer tools console other than from an unrelated script that I broke on purpose that's activating on 'a.arrow'. For some reason, the slider is simply not appearing.

The tutorial was rather straightforward and I'm at a loss for what's wrong. I've included the pertinent code below to see if there's something obvious I'm missing. I'll also include a link to the page in question:

https://restaurantex1.wpengine.com/about/

To see it: UN: demo  PW: password

I am aware that there is a WordPress specific plugin for this, but it has a visual editor that I'd prefer not include with the website we're building... which is why I was attempting to use the simpler jQuery only plugin instead.

Code to display Revolution slider:

```
<div class="rev_slider_wrapper" style="overflow: visible;height: 600px;display: block;position: relative;">

<!-- the ID here will be used in the JavaScript below to initialize the slider -->
<div id="rev_slider_1" class="rev_slider" style="">

    <ul>
        <!-- MINIMUM SLIDE STRUCTURE -->
        <li data-transition="fade">

            <!-- SLIDE'S MAIN BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
            <img src="https://restaurantex1.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/notgeneric_bg3.jpg" alt="Sky" class="rev-slidebg">

        </li>

        <!-- MINIMUM SLIDE STRUCTURE -->
        <li data-transition="fade">

            <!-- SLIDE'S MAIN BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
            <img src="https://restaurantex1.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/notgeneric_bg5.jpg" alt="Ocean" class="rev-slidebg">

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Enqueuing scripts in WordPress, which is working and not returning any errors in the console:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'revolution_settings', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/revolution/css/settings.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'revolution_layers', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/revolution/css/layers.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'revolution_navigation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/revolution/css/navigation.css' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'revolutiontools_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.1', false);

wp_enqueue_script( 'revolution_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.1', false);
```

Script in footer of site above closing  tag to activate slider:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#rev_slider_1').show().revolution({

        /* options are 'auto', 'fullwidth' or 'fullscreen' */
        sliderLayout: 'auto',

        /* basic navigation arrows and bullets */
        navigation: {

            arrows: {
                enable: true,
                style: 'hesperiden',
                hide_onleave: false
            },

            bullets: {
                enable: true,
                style: 'hesperiden',
                hide_onleave: false,
                h_align: 'center',
                v_align: 'bottom',
                h_offset: 0,
                v_offset: 20,
                space: 5
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The page link shows error on [line 429 as show in screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/PXtrR). It should be `jQuery(document).ready...`

Comment: The script at footer needs [to be fixed](https://pastebin.com/pSw2ANYR) first.

Comment: Thanks @AmitKB. I know there was an issue there, which I've fixed now to clean up the console, but I'm still not seeing the Revolution slider test on the About page at all... and I'm not seeing any errors in the console either. I do see the jQuery files for Revolution Slider running in the Network view on Developer Tools, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Set up [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) working Revolution Slider with just slider HTM and  Script and CSS resource pointing to your domain.